# Cannot save the merged images in proper position

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am new to android.Trying first time this code.
 I am saving three images, two images are small and one is large. I am trying to adjust the small ones position on large and merge that image into one but as I am clicking on the done button it is not saved properly on the position which I select for small image. I am moving the small image n large image and trying to save the image at that position where I stop. Making an photo editor like app.

My code is:
    For Save button

```
case R.id.bdone:
mTempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";//location
File mtempFile = new File(mTempDir);
if(!mtempFile.exists())
{
    mtempFile.mkdir();
}
mSaveImageName = "Test.jpg";//name of image to be merged

//myImage.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
//myImage.layout(0, 0, myImage.getMeasuredWidth(), myImage.getMeasuredHeight());

myImage.buildDrawingCache();
myBitmap  =  myImage.getDrawingCache();
myImage1.buildDrawingCache();
myBitmap1 = myImage1.getDrawingCache();
myImage2.buildDrawingCache();
myBitmap2 = myImage2.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(),myBitmap.getHeight(),myBitmap.getConfig());
myImage.setImageBitmap(mBackground);//Main bitmap
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBackground);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap ,new Matrix(), null);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1,x-dx,y-dy, null);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap2,x-dx,y-dx, null);
try
{
    mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mBackground);
    Bitmap mNewSaving = mBitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
    String ftoSave = mTempDir + mSaveImageName;
    File mFile = new File(ftoSave);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
    mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,100, out);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException  e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
break;
```

Please answer my question as soon as possible.